react native axios network error post for https
in my react native app
suddenly some device is stuck on network errors and can not apply any request
even if they reinstalled the app they stuck on network error
"react-native": "0.74.1",
"axios": "^1.7.3",
the error log is
{
  "message": "Network Error",
  "name": "AxiosError",
  "stack": "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at anonymous (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:1556:1290)\n    at call (native)\n    at dispatchEvent (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:136:5650)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:129:8891)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:129:4822)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:129:7606)\n    at apply (native)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:52:789)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:49:906)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:49:915)\n    at apply (native)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:3898)\n    at anonymous (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:694)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:2529)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:665)\n    at ?anon_0_ (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:1532:629)\n    at throw (native)\n    at n (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:7:74)\n    at s (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:7:322)\n    at tryCallOne (address at InternalBytecode.js:1:1180)\n    at anonymous (address at InternalBytecode.js:1:1874)\n    at apply (native)\n    at anonymous (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:123:1668)\n    at k (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:123:499)\n    at w (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:123:889)\n    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:123:3059)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:2897)\n    at anonymous (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:984)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:2529)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:942)\n    at value (/data/user/0/com.ukkera.student/files/CodePush/44b7e2c3628b0100789c76ed4c664c5d0f2862ce56c593bf4044d93ed26de5c3/CodePush/index.android.bundle:37:722)",
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
      "xhr",
      "http",
      "fetch"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "lang": "ar"
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "https://apis.ukkera.com/api/v1/student/private/gate",
    "data": "{\"user\":\"01032176793\",\"password\":\"\",\"password_confirmation\":\"\",\"device_id\":\"dde318d99ccc05f3\",\"device_type\":\"RMX3261 application\"}"
  },
  "code": "ERR_NETWORK"
}

post https request and it should return normal reponse
